# How to make a scroll view get on top of a frame layout when scrolling?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I have a constraint layout which contains a frame layout and scroll view. I want it so that when I scroll down my scroll view gets on top of the frame layout (sort of like snapchat profile page). Here's my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="215dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="#464646">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_picture"
        android:id="@+id/banner"/>
</FrameLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/profileback">
</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[The desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXcqh.png)

I'm new to android and I couldn't figure it out if anyone could provide a tutorial or any help that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you draw a picture or provide a mockup of what you want this to look like?

Comment: I have added a simple drawing, I hope that help explain

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure exactly what you are trying to do. I'll do my best to give you some ideas:

- You currently have set marginTop of the ScrollView to 200dp. When the user scrolls down you could programatically change the marginTop of the ScrollView to 0dp.
- You could remove the marginTop from the ScrollView and constrain the top of the ScrollView so that it would start at the bottom of the FrameLayout. When the user scrolls down you could set the visibility of the FrameLayout to GONE.

You will have to add a gesture detector to detect the scroll-down gesture to make the changes.